# Is it possible to identify where this photo was taken?

Tags: locations

[image]

Does anyone know where this photo was taken? Or at least what area/city it is of?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, what exactly would that change? You really don't need a perfect scan to be able to identify the place if you ever been there. If you weren't it's highly unlikely you'd know the answer anyway.

Comment: @Olin, sometimes taking a photo from directly above casts an excessively obscuring shadow. If there were to be complaints about this question, it should be that identifying locations is not a photography problem.

Comment: Are you interested in the photograph, or the location?

Comment: Wrong SE.  Post this in geography or history

Answer (score 13):

Calton Hill, Edinburgh, Scotland; the view is similar but not identical to [this photo](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@55.9551877,-3.182575,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipOpwzL-Wkgq6-l-8fGSl5212MPw_bWOZyNZhcY!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOpwzL-Wkgq6-l-8fGSl5212MPw_bWOZyNZhcY%3Dw129-h86-k-no!7i4898!8i3265).

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you already know this place or use a process to locate it (reverse image search)?

Comment: @Corey I recognised it immediately. It's a popular spot to visit in Edinburgh, not least for the view you get over the city.

Comment: That is a famous place. Also instantly recognized it just from knowledge, I have never been there even.